# A word for something in my mind?

Tags: word-choice

What would be a good word to fit in this sentence:

> I have this idea that I've been [...] for some time now.

Somehow, "thinking about" doesn't seem like a good choice here. I'm looking for a word that would mean something like *"processing in my mind".*

Comment: _thinking of, considering, investigating, ridiculing, ruminating on, playing with..._ The possibilities are many!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible single word that fits your request is

> ponder

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://dreaminginneverland.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/think.jpg))</sub>

> I have this idea that I've been pondering for some time now.

> He pondered the various possibilities before acting.
> *He thought about what to do beforehand*

For two words

> mulling over

would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Depends what sort of idea and what sort of thinking. Possibilities include: thinking about, considering, mulling over, dreading, working on, debating ... probably dozens more.

Comment: Yes, I think "considering" is probably the most common word to use here.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two words:

*Hatch*  v. tr.(used figuratively)

to contrive or devise (a scheme, plot, etc)

*Devise* v. tr.,which means

Plan or invent (a complex procedure, system, or mechanism) by careful thought.
But I believe the variants are unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

for one word, I would use "cogitating". From the word "cogitate", it means to think on or think around a subject matter. One synonym for this is also "ponder", so I would also agree with Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the issue **pondering** is very good for a simple set of soft circumstances, but evaluating is more easily understood and correct if the circumstance/issue is hard or complex.

As in, "I was pondering what the size my cat's house should be." or "I was **evaluating** the structural differences in manmade materials used in buildings today."

Both are correct, yet they carry a very different connotation!